# Define mu4e dynamic shortcuts

Tags: emacs

I manage multiple email accounts with mu4e using contexts (introduced in mu4e 0.9.16)

I would like to set my maildir shortcuts dynamically based on the variables defined by my contexts, but I am having trouble.

This code works for a static shortcut:

```
(setq mu4e-maildir-shortcuts '(("/Inbox" . ?i)))
```

I want `"/Inbox"` to be replaced with the value of `mu4e-inbox-folder` for the current context. I expect something like the following to work:

```
(setq mu4e-maildir-shortcuts '(((message mu4e-inbox-folder) . ?i)))
```

But it does not seem to define any shortcut.
Is the syntax incorrect, or is it not possible to define dynamic shortcuts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your context-specific shortcuts as part of the `:vars` section of your context, ie.

```
:vars '(( ... 
     other settings 
     ...
     (mu4e-maildir-shortcuts .  ( ("/archive"     . ?a)
                                  ("/inbox"       . ?i)
                                   .... )))
        ....
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it makes sense to do it this way.

The only downside is that it does cause more configuration than I would have liked :)